# Equivalent of WithEvents VBA in Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, vba, com, activex

I am porting an Excel macro to Qt/C++.

This macro uses ActiveX and COM to communicate with another application ([Pulse Labshop](http://www.bksv.com/products/pulse-analyzer/pulse-platform/pulse-labshop.aspx) from [Brüel & Kjaer](http://www.bkhome.com/)).

The Excel macro intercepts Labshop notification through a `WithEvents` variable.

How can I implement the same behaviour in C++? The Qt signal/slot mechanism does not seem to be possible here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Qt can generate specific QAxObject from dll and tlb.

For this project, the supplier gave me a tlb file.

In the pro file:

```
TYPELIBS = lib/Pulse.tlb
TYPELIBS = $$system( dumpcpp lib/Pulse.tlb -nometaobject -o src/controller/Pulse )
```

Then a Pulse.h file is generated. The classes have slots and signals. So it is easy to intercept events.

The reason why it didn't work was because the Pulse Labshop licence was expired.

Answer (score 0):

`WithEvents` is the keyword used in VB and VBA to invoke code in the VB runtime which does everything necessary to set up a callback mechanism using [the COM Connectable Objects architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You need to read up on this architecture, and its related interfaces `IConnectionPoint`, etc; implement the event sink interface in your C++ code; and then add the code to register your sink with Pulse Labshop's event source.

All this work done with one 'magic' keyword is one good reason why VB was so popular in its day.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is a good start. Do you have an implementation example of this solution?